# Add a login page in my Onsenui app

Tags: javascript, mobile, onsen-ui, monaca

I'd like to set a login page before entering the main page. 
How can I do that just before this instruction :

```
<ons-screen page="sliding_menu.html"></ons-screen>
```

I use The Monaca IDE

Thanks for the help

Charles

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try this way:

**index.html**

```
<ons-screen page="login.html"
```

**login.js**

```
function LoginController($scope){
    $scope.login = function(id, password){
        $scope.ons.screen.presentPage('sliding_menu.html');
    }
}
```

**login.html**

```
    <div class="page center" ng-controller="LoginController">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <ons-text-input placeholder="id" ng-model="id">             
            </ons-text-input>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <input type="password" placeholder="password" ng-model="password" class="topcoat-text-input">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <ons-button ng-click="login(id, password)">
                Login
            </ons-button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo:
http://onsenui.github.io/stackoverflow/sliding_menu_login/app/

Download src:
http://onsenui.github.io/stackoverflow/sliding_menu_login.zip

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for :-D...And by the way, your Framework rocks !! Thanks so much !

Comment: @Tamura How do I redirect the page using javascript? My app would check for local storage object. If present, it would skip the `login.html` to `sliding_menu.html`

Comment: you can bind the page of ons-screen to a controller variable. eg. <ons-screen page="{{initialPage}}". then based on the local storage value, you change the initialPage variable.

Comment: I could be a moron but does ons-screen still exist?