# Login screen redirecting to sliding-menu post authentication

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

First off, I know this has been [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22144654/add-a-login-page-in-my-onsenui-app) for < 1.1, but due to core changes to onsen-ui it is no longer valid...

SOOOO I must ask again, what is the "approved onsen-ui" way to present a page without a menu system to be used as a login view (assuming somehow with ons-page in place of the now removed ons-screen), and route it to a ons-sliding-menu based page post authentication?

Cheers :)

Comment: Did you find an alternative to ons-screen? it seems I'm in a similar situation. If you solved this issue I would appreciate it if you shared how.

Comment: I wrote a work around involving enabling and disabling the swipe capabilities that does what I needed. I will post an example when I get a moment.